# TFS pre-checkin step

Tags: tfs

When a developer want to check in his code to TFS, I want to add a pre-checkin step at the server level where the latest piece of code has to hit an API for validation, then allowing the developer to check in to TFS. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below ways to achieve that:

1. If your code is in a Team Foundation version control (TFVC) repo,
   use    **gated check-in** to protect against breaking changes.
   Create a build definition,enable the `gated check-in`. When a
   developers try    to check-in, they are prompted to build their
   changes, the changes    will only be checked in when the build
   succeed. See [TFVC gated    check-in](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/triggers#gated) for details.
2. Install the [Colin's ALM Checkin Policies](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ColinD.ColinsALMCheckinPoliciesVS2015andVSO) in each developer's VS
   client machine. You can use the **Code Review Policy**, enforce code
   review before check in the changes.
3. Using server-side policy/plug-ins (you may need to write your own
   policy as needed), reference below articles:

   - [Extending TFS’ default behavior using server-side plug-ins](https://blogs.msmvps.com/vstsblog/2014/05/12/extending-tfs-default-behavior-using-server-side-plug-ins/)
   - [TFS Server-side check-in policy for git repositories](http://almsports.net/tfs-server-side-check-in-policy-for-git-repositories/1025/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Andy-MSFT. Server side plugins looks, it can solve the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom check-in policy; you can use this [link](https://github.com/colindembovsky/ColinsALMCornerCheckinPolicies/tree/vs2017) for a starter.